# Word Add-in Get full Document text WITH INDICATOR?

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-web-addins

There is already a question answering related to this topic: [Word Add-in Get full Document text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41063377/word-add-in-get-full-document-text)
However, this method can't extract the indicator/bullet points.
Is there a way we can do this? I expect the text to be exactly the same as we manually `select all` then `copy` a Word document.

*The reason behind this: I'm building a question bank from a microsoft word document. Several tools offer text extraction, however, it usually ignores the bullet point.

I use keywords like `A.` `B.` `C.` `D.` etc to detect the choices. However, if the author writing choices using indicator/bullet point, this method fails.*

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

For each paragraph in the document, you can identify whether it is a list item by calling [isListItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.paragraph?view=word-js-preview#word-word-paragraph-islistitem-member).

If it is, you can call [listItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.paragraph?view=word-js-preview#word-word-paragraph-listitem-member) to get the item.

The [listString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.listitem?view=word-js-preview#word-word-listitem-liststring-member) property in [Word.ListItem class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.listitem?view=word-js-preview#word-word-listitem-liststring-member) can help you get the list item bullet, number, or picture as a string.

Here is an example that how to extract the bullets in the document.

```
Word.run(async (context) => {
  var paragraphs = context.document.body.paragraphs;
  paragraphs.load("$none");
  await context.sync();
  for (let i = 0; i < paragraphs.items.length; i++) {
    paragraphs.items[i].load("isListItem");
    paragraphs.items[i].load("text");
    await context.sync();
    if (paragraphs.items[i].isListItem) {
      paragraphs.items[i].load("listItem");
      await context.sync();
      console.log(paragraphs.items[i].listItem.listString + " " + paragraphs.items[i].text);
    } else {
      console.log(paragraphs.items[i].text);
    }
  }
});
```

The document is printed to the console paragraph by paragraph with all bullets retained.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the numbered lists (list paragraphs) to plain text with a simple piece of vba.

See here [convert lists to text](https://word.tips.net/T001857_Converting_Lists_to_Text.html)

Comment: At least summarize the article to which you refer. The idea here is to have answers be self-contained without reference to external links. If needed, use quotations (with attribution).