# How do I get Microsoft word document text as a string?

Tags: javascript, word-addins

I am new to Microsoft Office addins and JS. I am trying to develop a Microsoft Word add-in that converts selected text in the document into QR code. So my problem is getting selected text in the document as simple string.
Nothing I tried so far worked. Here is a link for getting the whole text in a document that helped a bit: [Word Add-in Get full Document text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41063377/word-add-in-get-full-document-text). What I need is how to get selected text as a string. I need your help please. I tried the following:

```
txt = "";
  await Word.run(async (context) => {
    var documentBody = context.document.body;
    context.load(documentBody);
    return context.sync().then(function () {
      console.log(documentBody.text); //full document text
      console.log(document.getSelection.text); //selected only
      txt = documentBody.text.getSelection();
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [Script Lab](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-US/product/office/wa104380862). The first sample in Word does exactly what you need:

```
$("#run").click(() => tryCatch(run));

function run() {
  return Word.run(function(context) {
    var range = context.document.getSelection();
    range.font.color = "red";
    range.load("text");

    return context.sync().then(function() {
      console.log('The selected text was "' + range.text + '".');
    });
  });
}

/** Default helper for invoking an action and handling errors. */
function tryCatch(callback) {
  Promise.resolve()
    .then(callback)
    .catch(function(error) {
      // Note: In a production add-in, you'd want to notify the user through your add-in's UI.
      console.error(error);
    });
}
```